# Причины обязательного вызова родительского конструктора в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ооп

У нас имеется код с использованием ООП на js:

```
class FirstName {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getSecret() {
        return 'Secret';
    }
}

class SecondName extends FirstName {
    constructor(lastName) {
        super();
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

const user = new FirstName('FirstName');
const user2 = new SecondName('SecondName');
```

Мне необходимо получать в экземплярах класса только имя или только фамилию. Нет нужды видеть там и то и то, но есть необходимость иметь доступ к методу getSecret и там и там. Как это сделать используя синтаксис классов?

Предполагается, что за кадром все должно работать так:

```
function FirstName(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

FirstName.prototype.getSecret = function() {
    return 'Secret';
}

function SecondName(lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(SecondName.prototype, FirstName.prototype);

const user = new FirstName('FirstName');
const user2 = new SecondName('SecondName');
```

Этот синтаксис позволяет мне сделать задуманное, так как если я выведу в консоль user2 я увижу:

```
{lastName: "SecondName"}
```

При использовании первого подхода я бы увидел:

```
{name: undefined, lastName: "SecondName"}
```

Вопрос: почему в вызове конструктора дочернего класса должен быть всегда использован super() ?

Comment: Потому что иначе это не наследование, а какая-то бессмыслица. Сделайте отдельно класс в котором есть getSecret и отнаследуйте от него независимо друг от друга FirstName и SecondName

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно https://javascript.info/mixins

Comment: В конструкторе ключевое слово super() используется как функция, вызывающая родительский конструктор. Её необходимо вызвать до первого обращения к ключевому слову this в теле конструктора. - это часть синтаксиса. Можете не писать, JS не умрет. но вы не получите  наследования

Comment: @AzizUmarov я не могу НЕ использовать в том то и дело, он умирает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему тогда в пхп хочу вызову хочу нет?))

Comment: Потому что авторы PHP сделали по другому.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103/1016033

Comment: Вопрос хороший, а ответ отстой))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Во первых классы в JavaScript это не просто "синтаксический сахар" как многие любят говорить. Например, вы можете получить `undefined` в `this` вместо привычного `window` в случае потери контекста. Существует еще ряд подводных камней при работе с классами в js.

Во втором примере использовано наследование на основе прототипов (оно и с классами в JavaScript будет основано на прототипах и не будет подразумевать копирование свойств и методов, а будет делегировать их, но скроет эту логику от вас, инкапсулирует).

Почему именно делегирование а не копирование? Экономия памяти. Работая в браузере мы сильно ограничены по памяти.

Что такое `this` в теле функции? Оно будет указывать на текущий контекст. При попытке создать объект с помощью ключевого слова `new` будет выполнено 4 операции:

1. Будет создан объект `{}` и помещен в тело функции
2. Этот объект будет установлен как контекст для функции
3. Объект функции `prototype` будет установлен как `__proto__` у текущего, помещенного внутрь функции объекта
4. Будет возвращен объект созданный на шаге один

Единственный способ избавиться от шага 4 - это вернуть из функции другой объект.

Что такое `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Он берет прототип объекта справа и устанавливает его для прототипа объекта слева. Он берет прототип объекта справа и кладет его в геттер `__proto__` объекта слева. Он берет прототип объекта справа и расширяет собой прототип объекта слева.

Что такое `__proto__`?

Это объект, который являлся объектом `.prototype` у конструктора, с помощью которого объект был создан.

```
function a() {}
a.__proto__ === Function.prototype //true
({}).__proto__ === Object.prototype //true
```

Функция будет ссылаться на `Function.prototype`, объект на `Object.prototype` и все те свойства и методы, которые доступны в `prototype` будут доступны и для вновь созданных объектов. Переиспользование кода, делегирование кода. Это ООП в js. Функция получит `bind`, `call`; объект `toString`, `hasOwnProperty` и тд.
Геттер `__proto__` есть у любого объекта, кроме некоторых извращений вроде `Object.create(null)`.

Что такое `prototype`?

Это просто объект, который есть у любой функции, кроме стрелочных. В случае использования функции как конструктора он будет помещен в свойство `__proto__` объекта. Пункт 3 выше.

---

То есть теперь можно восстановить цепочку события для наследования на основе прототипов и понять, что на выходе мы получим два объекта, `user` и `user2`, которые будут иметь доступ к одному объекту с методом `getSecret()`, но при этом ничего друг о друге не знать (за исключением некоторых извращений `user2.__proto__.__proto__.constructor` - `FirstName`). Пример выше нарушает парадигму ООП, используя композицию (prototype) осуществляется наследование (делегирование), но сам объект `user2` не получает свойства, нарушая LS принцип.

Это можно было поправить, например так:

```
function FirstName(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

FirstName.prototype.getSecret = function() {
    return 'Secret';
}

function SecondName(firstName, lastName) {
    FirstName.call(this, firstName);
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(SecondName.prototype, FirstName.prototype);

const user = new FirstName('FirstName');
const user2 = new SecondName('FirstName', 'SecondName');
```

То есть это абсолютно нормальное поведение, когда объект расширяющий функционал, наследуя от другого объекта получает все то, что в этом "другом" объекте было. В противном случае можно было бы прийти к выводу, что проектируемая система не нуждается в классическом наследовании и тут больше подойдет композиция и какой-нибудь наиболее подходящий паттерн для реализации поставленной задачи (или даже их группа).

Теперь что касается классов:

Если вкратце - таже причина, но теперь такое поведение стоит "по умолчанию". Просто они вот так решили. Например, в PHP можно и не вызывать:

```
class A {
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __contruct(string $secondName)
    {
        $this->secondName = $secondName;
    }
}

$b = new B('SecondName');
print_r($b);
```

Но `$this->name = $name;` из класса `A` все ровно будет выполнено. PHP версии 8.2 и выше будет выдавать `Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property B::$name is deprecated` на такое. Но результат будет и в самом деле объект с одним свойством. В JavaScript такое просто не получится сделать:

```
class A {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(lastName) {
        // Uncaught ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using 'this' in derived class constructor
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

То есть воспринимайте это как полезную подсказку от редактора и не более.